# Calculating total depth of a variable

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, metpy

I have calculated the Moist Brunt-Vaisala frequency.
Let's say that the variable is `moistb` and has a dimension of `[height, lat, lon]`.

I would like to plot the horizontal distribution of the total depth of the `moistb`.
How do I calculate the total depth? The idea is to sum all the depth of `moistb` in each grid point. Is there a way to do this with metpy?

For reference, here's an example as shown by [Schumacher and Johnson (2008)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ZKA.gif)
where they plot the horizontal distribution of total depth (m).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like in this case that you're working with data stored in an Xarray `DataArray`. If so, the way to do what you're looking for is:

```
moistb.sum(dim='height')
```

You can also do this with regular numpy arrays (or a `DataArray`) by using the `axis` argument, which corresponds to the number of the dimension in order. So for the order listed above this would be:

```
moistb.sum(axis=0)
```

For more information see the [Xarray docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sum.html?highlight=sum#xarray-dataarray-sum) or the [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html).